# Lost variable data in the Unity UI for my game after a bug with Unity. Is there a way to get that data from a previous versionof the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title explains, I had a bug with linking my game in Unity to the cloud and unlinking it in a way that nearly cost me months of progress. I managed to find a fix for it but all the variables I manually set in the UI for the scripts attached to gameobjects and what not got wiped. That's a lot of data, is there a way to recover it from a previous save that might have (only a few) variances via say a few different variables in the UI and such?

Comment: You mean .. you lost your scene/prefab assets ...?

Comment: revert using the source control you're using to a time when it worked?

Comment: I'm new to this and didn't have version control, which I am going to set up.

I don't mean prefab assets, I mean the variables you can enter in the UI, things you made public in the scripting.

I was able to ultimately recover most of my work. The navmesh needs some work but that's fine. I have such a bad habit of asking questions then solving the problem right after. 

I just pasted the project settings folder of an older version in and then adjusted things from the warning I was getting in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, if you don't set up version control, copy/pasting the project settings from an older version and adjusting from there might work and did in this case.

I had to deal with some warnings that I cleared up with the audio mixer, needed to create a exposed parameter, and muck about with the UI settings. I oppened up an older version and plugged in the variables values.